# Vue/JavaScript - Stop 'preventDefault' from affecting child components

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to create a modal dialog in Vue. When the dialog is open, I want the page scrolling to be disabled but the user should still be able to scroll the dialog, and I was trying to achieve this with `preventDefault`. My component looks like this:

```html
<!--Modal.vue-->
<template>
  <div v-show="open" class="modal" @scroll.stop.prevent @wheel.stop.prevent>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="dialog">
        <button @click="$emit('close')">CLOSE</button>
        <Paragraphs />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Paragraphs from "./Paragraphs";
export default {
  components: {
    Paragraphs,
  },

  props: {
    open: Boolean,
  },
};
</script>

<!--some scoped CSS here-->
```

> Full working example on the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-pond-3zrxsf

The problem is that while this arrangement is preventing page scrolling, it is also freezing scrolling on the dialog itself, which I don't want. And apparently `stopPropagation` only prevents bubbling *up*, but not *down* the DOM tree, so that isn't helping either. What can I do to achieve this?

> **Note:** I do not want to set the `overflow-y` property of the `body` tag as that takes away the scrollbars completely and has a jittery effect of everything shifting to the side by a few pixels when the dialog is opened or closed.

Comment: perhaps this custom directive [v-scroll-lock](https://github.com/phegman/v-scroll-lock) will help - here's the [demo page](https://v-scroll-lock.peterhegman.com/) - looks like it'll do exactly what you want

Comment: note: it's a simple wrap for [body-scroll-lock](https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock)

Comment: This turns the scrollbar on and off, which is what I am trying to avoid, as mentioned in the description above.

Comment: Sure it does - but there's no jiggling evident as far as I can see - perhaps if you add `body { padding-right:15px; }` to your style the jiggle will disappear